# Missing $ or } inserted. Table using \thead

Tags: tables, errors

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Data for the second measurement.}
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
\hline
\thead{Current \textit{I}/ \si{\milli\ampere} \\ $\Delta I \approx$  0 
\si{\milli\ampere}} & \thead{Voltage \textit{$V_{1}$}/ \si{\volt} \\ $\Delta 
V_{1}=\pm$  0.01 \si{\volt}}  & \thead{Voltage \textit{$V_{2}$}/ \si{\volt} 
\\ $\Delta V_{2}=\pm$  0.0001 \si{\volt}} &  \thead{Voltage $\frac{V_{1}} 
{V_{2}}$/ \si{\volt} \\ $\pm$ 0.5 \%}  \bigstrut\\
\hline
1   & 0.50 & 0.5837 & 0.8566044  \bigstrut\\
\hline
2   & 1.00 & 1.1875 & 0.8421053  \bigstrut\\
\hline
3   & 1.50 & 1.7928 & 0.8366801  \bigstrut\\
\hline
4   & 2.00 & 2.4034 & 0.8321544  \bigstrut\\
\hline
5   & 2.50 & 3.0182 & 0.8283083  \bigstrut\\
\hline
6   & 3.00 & 3.6359 & 0.8251052  \bigstrut\\
\hline
7   & 3.50 & 4.2556 & 0.8224457  \bigstrut\\
\hline
8   & 4.00 & 4.8728 & 0.8208833  \bigstrut\\
\hline
9   & 4.50 & 5.4929 & 0.8192394  \bigstrut\\
\hline
10  & 5.00 & 6.1217 & 0.8167666  \bigstrut\\
\hline
11  & 5.50 & 6.7480 & 0.8150563  \bigstrut\\
\hline
12  & 6.00 & 7.3694 & 0.8141775  \bigstrut\\

\hline
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The error occurs in the ninth line, but I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: The packages and the document class are missing, give a minimum example (MWE) https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: I made an edit. Hope it's OK.

Comment: after fixing line 2 to load `xcolor` the provided code compiles (on TeXLive 2018 not tested with earlier packages)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

- your mwe can't be compiled, missing are document preamble
- why you use `H` for table placement? this can cause problems. let allow float environment to flow
- code in the your mwe has many errors (missing `}`)
- i would redesign your table as you see on image above. for this i use

  - `S` column type from the package `siunitx` and rules from the package `booktabs`
  - remove all lines in table body
  - change column headers (btw $V_1/V_2$ is ratio without unit!)
  - use `\SI` macro for your values with units
- i wonder why you write voltage with seven decimal digits when accuracy of numbers is only 0.5 %? three decimal digits should be sufficient ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Data for the second measurement.}
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.0]
                S[table-format=1.2]
                S[table-format=1.4]
                S[table-format=2.7]}
    \toprule
{Current}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Voltages}
        & {Voltages ratio}                  \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
{\thead{$I$ (mA)\\
        $\Delta I \approx \SI{0}{\milli\ampere}$}}
    & {\thead{$V_{1}$ (V)\\
             $\Delta V_{1}=\SI{\pm 0.01}{\volt}$}}
        & {\thead{$V_{2}$ (V)\\
                 $\Delta V_{2}=\SI{\pm 0.0001}{\volt}$}}
            &  {\thead{$V_{1}/V_{2}$\\
                      \SI{\pm0.5}{\%}}}     \\
    \midrule
1   & 0.50 & 0.5837 & 0.8566044  \\
2   & 1.00 & 1.1875 & 0.8421053  \\
3   & 1.50 & 1.7928 & 0.8366801  \\
4   & 2.00 & 2.4034 & 0.8321544  \\
    \addlinespace
5   & 2.50 & 3.0182 & 0.8283083  \\
6   & 3.00 & 3.6359 & 0.8251052  \\
7   & 3.50 & 4.2556 & 0.8224457  \\
8   & 4.00 & 4.8728 & 0.8208833  \\
    \addlinespace
9   & 4.50 & 5.4929 & 0.8192394  \\
10  & 5.00 & 6.1217 & 0.8167666  \\
11  & 5.50 & 6.7480 & 0.8150563  \\
12  & 6.00 & 7.3694 & 0.8141775  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```